# How to pass a parameter to a MiddlewareFunc?

Tags: rest, http, go, backend, mux

I'm working on a small demo that tries to explain how a basic HTTP handler works, and I found the following example:

```golang
package main

func router() *mux.Router {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    auth := router.PathPrefix("/auth").Subrouter()
    auth.Use(auth.ValidateToken)
    auth.HandleFunc("/api", middleware.ApiHandler).Methods("GET")
    return router
}

func main() {
    r := router()
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

```golang
package auth

func ValidateToken(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var header = r.Header.Get("secret-access-token")

        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(r)
        header = strings.TrimSpace(header)

        if header == "" {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("Missing auth token")
            return
        }

        if header != "SecretValue" {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("Auth token is invalid")
            return
        }


        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(fmt.Sprintf("Token found. Value %s", header))
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

```golang
package middleware

func ApiHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("SUCCESS!")
    return
}
```

Everything is understandable, but it pop-out to my mind two questions:

- Why it doesn't require to send a parameter in this line: `secure.Use(auth.ValidateToken)`?
- If I wanted to send an extra parameter to this `auth.ValidateToken` func, (example, a string, for which this header should be compared instead of `"SecretValue"`), how can this be done?

Thanks in advance, I'm kind of new at using golang and wanted to learn more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`auth.Use` takes a function as argument, and `auth.ValidateToken` is the function you pass. If you want to send an argument to `auth.ValidateToken`, you can write a function that takes that argument, and returns a middleware function, like this:

```
func GetValidateTokenFunc(headerName string) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
     return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var header = r.Header.Get(headerName)
        ...
     }
  }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
    auth.Use(auth.GetValidateTokenFunc("headerName"))
```

Comment: That worked like a charm!

I find it kind of confusing the fact that Go can return functions. I have to keep studying.